# PHP page link and submit form again

Tags: javascript, php

I have created this link for pagination. Pagination is working fine, but I wish to submit the form again. But the form is not submitting by the javascript written. The form is basically a search input form

```
echo "[ <a href='$_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME]?Page=$i' onclick='document.getElementById(pesquisar).submit();'>$i</a> ]";
```

Comment: question should be edited with more details

Comment: Question should be clarified, a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use javascript instead: give id to your `a` like `id='submitForm'` then put this javascript:

```
$('#submitForm').click(function(){
  $('#formid').submit();
});
```

hope this help...